# Creating a site map of an FTP site

Tags: ftp, sitemap

Where I work, we maintain an FTP site that needs occasional cleanup.

Are there any tools out there to create a site map of an FTP site? It would greatly simplify clean up tasks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not used it and its not free - although $19 is not far from free - [ftp space](http://ftp-space.qarchive.org/?bcsi_scan_CAE56E148E64F880=0)

Answer (score 1):

How automatic do you want it to be ?  and in What language ?

I've used the Perl Net::FTP module to craft a spider to walk the structure and report differences.

[Perl ftp list directory](http://www.example-code.com/perl/ftp_listDirectory.asp)